# Access Property values at run time from a mapping function

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection

I have a list of objects let's say it is `FirstName, LastName, Age, Address`.
It reality it is about **20** of those.
Now I want to populate an `excel` file. I do know in advance that for example FirstName's value should go to `Column "D"` in the excel file and for example LastName'a value should go to excels `column "G"` , etc.
So currently I am doing it in a **boring** way which is something like this:

```
int rowNum = 5;
foreach (var item in myData)
{
    SetExcelCellValue("D", rowNum, item.FirstName);
    SetExcelCellValue("G", rowNum, item.LastName);
    SetExcelCellValue("F", rowNum, item.Address);
    // ... imagine 10 more of things like that ... 
}
rowNum++;
```

I feel like I can do it in a **smarter** way but I couldn't quite figure it out. I feel like I need a `dictionary` and pre-populate my `dictionary` and say for example `FirstName -> D` , ...
but then I am not sure how would I access its values at run time? Would I need `reflection` ? That's the part I am not quite sure how to do.

Thanks.